# Knowing a python script has something to read from stdin when launched by crontab

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cron, stdin

I have a python script that is run by the crontab and can be executed manually.

This script takes as an input:

- either the value from `-i` argument,
- or whatever comes from `stdin` through a `pipe`.

The code should be something like this:

```
if ???: #test to check if there is some data in stdin
  print("I have data from stdin!")
else:
  print("I have no data from stdin!")
```

The script is executed as follows:

```
$ ./myscript.py -i myInput
> I have no data from stdin!

$ cat myInput | ./myscript.py
> I have data from stdin!
```

I have tried several methods that work fine when executed via the console, but don't work as expected when executed by the crontab : the script always considers there IS data from stdin.

First test:

```
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
  print("I have data from stdin!")
else:
  print("I have no data from stdin!")
```

I think this one does not work because because there is no tty in crontab mode so the first statement is always true.

Second test:

```
import stat
mode = os.fstat(sys.stdin.fileno()).st_mode
if stat.S_ISFIFO(mode):
  print("I have data from stdin!")
else:
  print("I have no data from stdin!")
```

Third test:

```
import select
r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
if r:
  print("I have data from stdin!")
else:
  print("I have no data from stdin!")
```

Is there a correct way to make it work for both console and crontab mode?

Comment: one possible work around is to check if you got the `-i` first, that way you don't need to check the pipe

Comment: I thought of it :) But I wish to have the value from pipe taken into account when both are specified (should not happen but who knows). Plus now that I searched for an answer, my curiosity must be satisfied!

Comment: when you try to get the data from the pipe does it freeze or do you get some value(possibly empty string)? if it freezes you could probably set the read on a timer and abort after a second, if you get an actual value, what is it?

Comment: It does not freeze, it will operate whatever value is found in stdin, possibly empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nullman already wrote in a comment it is better to check your command line options to decide if you want to try `stdin` or not.

Short summary: You cannot safely guess if you should read data from `stdin` by checking `stdin`. You should only rely on checking the command line to find out what is expected.

For example `cat` will use `stdin` only if no input file was specified as a command line argument or if the special file name `-` was specified.

---

All the tests in your examples will work in certain conditions only and will not work in other cases.

Checking if `stdin` is a TTY does not help. It will only tell you if it is connected to a terminal. Your script can get input from a terminal if the user types something or if it is a pseudo-terminal connected to something else. Your script can also get input from `stdin` if it is not connected to a terminal but to something else (pipe, file, socket,...)

Checking if `stdin` is a FIFO is also wrong because you can read data both from a pipe/fifo or from something else (file, socket, terminal,...).

Using `select` will not tell you if there is any data, but only if a `read` will not block. It also will not block on EOF. To distinguish these cases you would have to check the result of a `read` from `stdin`. Without a delay/timeout it might also tell you that a `read` would block if the data is **not yet** available.

There are more ways to use the script:

Instead of `cat myInput | ./myscript.py` you could also use `./myscript.py < myInput`. In the first case `stdin` will be a pipe, in the second case a file.

Or imagine `./myscript.py < /dev/null`. This will return EOF condition on the first `read`.
Or `./myscript.py <&-` which will close `stdin` leading to an error when you try to read from it.

If `stdin` is connected to a terminal a `read` might block if the user does not enter anything. This would happen if you call `./myscript.py`. You could use `select` to find out if data is available **now**, but you cannot find out if the user will enter data later. So your script does not know the intention of the user.

Comment: Thank you for these nice explanations. I guess I will have to handle it differently then, as Nullman also suggested.